# Recalculating absolute positioned elements position?

Tags: jquery, positioning, addeventlistener

I have some elements positioned absolutely, relative to document body.

When something is appended, somewhere inside DOM, then absolute positioned elements should be repositioned as well.

The question is, how to know that DOM was changed somewhere there inside?

The second idea was to listen to document height and width changes, which i think is the most efficient way to do it.

Are there any other ways to accomplish that?

**UPDATE**
http://jsfiddle.net/9nkq9/

Comment: Do your absolutely positioned elements _need_ to be absolutely positioned? Can you give us more detail and perhaps a jsfiddle of the html code please?

Comment: Well, actually yes, i need them to be absolutely positioned. Just a second i'll try to create some example on jsfiddle.

Comment: Have added some example to the main topic. The thing is, that i don't want to tell the black box to move, it should reposition himself on change.

Answer (score 1):

Do the absolutely positioned elements need to be positioned relative to the body?

By wrapping them in a container positioned relative you can acheive the result as I understand it:

http://jsfiddle.net/9nkq9/1/

Comment: Yes they need to be relative to body.