# CSS: Aligning elements of unknown size

Tags: css, html5-video

I'm building a video chat application based on https://apprtc.appspot.com/ (to run this application, you need to open the same URL in two separate tabs).

I'd like to make two changes to this reference application.

1. Center the video in the browser window.
2. Align the small video in the bottom right corner of the large video (similar to Skype).

I managed to solve #1 using http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/ but I cannot figure out #2. The problem is that the large video size is dynamic (WebRTC changes its size over time depending on CPU and bandwidth conditions). It also grows/shrinks as the browser window is resized (fit to view). When the large video changes size, the small video loses alignment.

**How do I align the small video to the bottom right corner of the large video when the latter's size changes over time?**

**UPDATE**: Please provide a solution with overlapping videos, not just boxes. Also, please make sure the videos grow/shrink as the browser window is grown/shrunk.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS positioning:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="big_video">
        test
         <div id="small_video">test2</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#big_video{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}

#small_video{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FhtCP/12/

Comment: The video size is unknown so I cannot specify width/height as you have done.

Comment: Height and width can be anything, I just provided that as an example so I had some boxes to work with.

Comment: Okay but I can't get your answer working for overlapping videos (as required by the question). I tried adding a <video> but "test2" does not overlap the video's bottom right corner. See http://jsfiddle.net/FhtCP/14/

Comment: Gili, I'm looking at your fiddle and it certainly does overlap it (though it's hard to see.) I added a bg color for better visibility. Since the video is larger than the frame it's drawn in, make sure you scroll all the way to the right to see it. http://jsfiddle.net/FhtCP/15/

Comment: @idrumgood, increase the width/height of the rendering frame (bottom-right box) and you will notice that the small video aligns to the bottom-right corner of the container instead of the bottom-right corner of the big video. Hence, this answer is incorrect.

Comment: Your issue is that you can only place video content inside the `<video>` tag. So the only way you're going to get what you want is to make sure the `#big_video` is the same size as the `<video>` so your `#small_video` can be positioned. Otherwise, `#small_video` has no way of figuring out where the lower left corner of `<video>` is.  Basically, control the size of your `<video>` and `#big_video`

Comment: @idrumgood, I get your point but as the question has already explained: the video size is unknown. I **cannot** assign it a fixed size. WebRTC dynamically resizes the video size depending on CPU and bandwidth usage (which changes over time).

Comment: Brian, as I have explained above, your solution fails to answer my question. Please correct or remove it altogether. Stackoverflow has incorrectly marked this question as answered because your solution has been up-voted too many times. So remove it so others are encouraged to provide a working solution.

Comment: @Gili I'm not telling you to set a fixed height/width on your video. I'm telling you to make sure that your containing box matches the dimensions of the video. Brian's solution is correct, or as correct as is possible.

Comment: @idrumgood, fair enough. How do I make sure my containing box matches the dimensions of the video if those dimensions keep on changing?

Comment: have you tried... width: 100% maybe? ...

Comment: @BrianGlaz, as mentioned by http://stackoverflow.com/q/7300242/14731 when a parent's dimension is updated, a child's absolute position does not get recalculated (which is what we want in this case) and it's not clear how to do so. Please update your answer with a more complete solution that contains *all* the elements required by the question: <video> tags, grow/shrink as the window grows/shrinks, etc.